# Getting error The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available

Tags: centos, php, openssl

I have setup an LAMP server in CentOS successfully and installed Magento, On clearing cache getting error as openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS.

I compiled PHP from source successfully `compiled ./configure --with-openssl` (No error but haven't provided the path)

I tried the following by re-configuring PHP from source.

I have installed `yum install openssl-devel` to the latest (Nothing to do)

Can anyone tell me how to find the path to be provided for with-openssl?

```
whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/lib64/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

On including `/usr/bin/openssl, /usr/lib64/openssl, /usr/include/openssl` as path to  **--with-openssl** getting error

> checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
>
> configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's

I don't know what I am missing with this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do yourself a favor + install latest Ubuntu + setup the ondrej PPAs for Apache + PHP. These PPAs will also pull in latest OpenSSL. With these PPAs, you can also switch between 5.6 + 7.0 + 7.1 + 7.2 easily. Building PHP from source is easy. Integrating it with Apache + OpenSSL + MaridDB + many other libraries will suck massive amounts of time. Then you'll have to repeat this process each time any underlying library changes.

Comment: I have centos in my server and my requirement lies like this, I need to install  everything from source, I am not well versed with linux, Is there any possibility to fix this with the same setup. How can I find the path to include with --with-openssl

Comment: How can I find the path to include with --with-openssl

Comment: Yes. Best way is to first install openssl + rebuild openssl each time an update comes out. Then do the same for Apache + PHP.  Keep in mind, based on the data you've provided, there's a high likelihood you're running a Linux Kernel that's hackable. If you go with this config, most of your time will be spent just trying to keep all this bandaged + running. Also, if you are running a hackable Kernel, you'll have to deal with continually cleansing your system of hacks, which will then immediately reappear. All very time consuming.

Comment: I have installed openssl with yum its up to date and i have reconfigured Apache and php its not working. phpinfo() shows its enabled from the above image I have attached but when I do  php -i | grep -i openssl  it shows open ssl is disabled.

Comment: I don't get what you say do you say me use ondrej PPAs for Apache.

Comment: ondrej PPAs provide latest stable releases of Apache + PHP + OpenSSL, back ported to many older OS versions. If you run these PPAs, then you'll always have access to latest performance + security fixes. Otherwise, you'll have to wait 6months to 1year for these updates, depending on exactly what OS version (LTS or non-LTS) you have installed.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way to fix the issue with the same setup. it seems to me a common issue when I searched but all the fix doesn't work foe me.

Comment: The exact same issue https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28652046/Openssl-enabled-via-web-but-disabled-when-using-php-cli.html#a40760081 I tried --with-openssl=/usr but getting error checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured php twice with and without --prefix

So there are two packages one on `/usr/local` and another on `/usr/local/php7` of same php version 7.1.10

Now my terminal points to `/usr/local/` and web points to `/usr/local/php7/`.

I need to do `/usr/local/php7/bin/php -m` to get the modules of Web

I have raised a new conversation, How to point web version to CLI [My CLI and web point to two different php path, How to fix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404934/my-cli-and-web-point-to-two-different-php-path-how-to-fix)